# get data with observables, subsscribe and http, angular

Tags: angular, http, observable, subscribe

im trying to get data from an API, ive come so far that i can get the data in controle.log and print it out with json. But, i cant get id, name,... from interface or class. I dont know why i cant get it. someone have a clue?

i have also tried movie[] class instead of IData[] but it doesnt make any diffrens.

```
export class MoviesService {

private showMovies = new Subject<IData[]>();
movies$ = this.showMovies.asObservable();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getServerData(){
    this.http.get<IData[]>("https://medieinstitutet-wie-products.azurewebsites.net/api/products").subscribe((dataFromApi: IData[]) =>
    this.showMovies.next(dataFromApi))
  }
}



export class ShowmoviesComponent implements OnInit {

 showMovies: IData [] = []
  constructor(private service: MoviesService) { }

  ngOnInit(): any {
    this.service.movies$.subscribe((dataFromService: IData[]) => {
      return this.showMovies = dataFromService,
      console.log(dataFromService)
    })
      this.service.getServerData()   
  }
}


export class Movies{
    id: string
    name: string
    description: string
    price: string
    imageUrl: string
    year: string
    added: string
    productCategory: string

    constructor(
        id: string, 
        name: string, 
        description: string, 
        price: string,
        imageUrl: string,
        year: string,
        added: string,
        productCategory: string){
        this.id = id
        this.name = name
        this.description = description
        this.price = price
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl
        this.year = year
        this.added = added
        this.productCategory = productCategory
    }
}


export interface IData{
 
        id: string
        name: string
        description: string
        price: string
        imageUrl: string
        year: string
        added: string
        productCategory: string
}

<div *ngFor="let m of showMovies">
    {{ showMovies | json}}
</div>
```

Comment: Why you're making this return : return this.showMovies = dataFromService,

Comment: without it i cant get the data to showMovie, and out to the html. i only get it in the console.log then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace your `subject` by a `BehaviorSubject`

Also, you are using the ngFor in the wrong way. It should be:

```
<div *ngFor="let m of showMovies">
    {{ m | json}}
</div>
```

To finish, don't forget to unsubscribe your observables:
In your case you can use `take(1)` as you need the first  ->

```
 this.http.get<IData[]>("https://medieinstitutet-wie-products.azurewebsites.net/api/products").pipe(take(1).subscribe((dataFromApi: IData[]) =>
    this.showMovies.next(dataFromApi))
  }
```

Comment: got: An argument for '_value' was not provided.
im very new at this, so trying to learn how it works. BehaviorSubject is nothing my teacher has talked about jet.

Comment: Ok, try to subscribe directly to your 'showMovies' subject on your component. Also, you need to us 'm' instead of your 'showMovies' in the template *ngFor.

Comment: Thank you so much. it was the mixup with the m and showMovie that was the problem.

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answere as accepted if this is fixing the issue

Comment: how do i do that? new to this place, cant fint the info